# angular-stl-model-viewer not working in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js, stl

I tried to add a stl-viewer to my angular project via the npm package angular-stl-model-viewer and installed all dependencies successfully.
the problem is, that its not showing.
Thats the link to the package: https://github.com/tevim/angular-stl-model-viewer

I checked the source code of the html page and found out that the angular-stl-viewer i've integrated to my page with the tag  creates inside the tag a div element and a canvas. and the width and height attribute of the canvas is zero. So there seems to be a problem. But I rendered my example stl-file "HalfDonut.stl" on an online stl-viewer successfully.
I also checkt the html source code from the demopage and it look the same except the width and height of the canvas.
demo page: https://tevim.github.io/angular-stl-model-viewer/examples/basic/dist/my-app/

Comment: Did anyone could test it quickly and just tell me if this is a general bug or just a issue that belongs to my angular/browser or whatever. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, apparently you need to add some CSS to get the viewer to appear:

```
stl-model-viewer {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

This was found in the angular-stl-model-viewer repository under examples:
https://github.com/tevim/angular-stl-model-viewer/tree/master/examples/basic/src/app